# Linking ready made external static library

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I have a ready made external static library (.a) that I want to link to my executable. How exactly can I do it with cmake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` command. But before that you might want to make sure CMake looks into correct directories by using `FIND_LIBRARY` or `LINK_DIRECTORIES`. All are documented in detail here: ([CMake help: TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3atarget_link_libraries)) ([CMake help: LINK_DIRECTORIES](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3alink_directories)) ([CMake help: FIND_LIBRARY](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3afind_library))

According to the comment by @Fraser, it is better to use `find_library` over `link_directories`.

Comment: I'd suggest using [`find_library`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:find_library) to get the full path to the library and then use just `target_link_libraries`.  The use of `link_directories` is discouraged - even in its own documentation.